How to prevent windows being scaled in SFML?
I am using SFML on MacOS. I have a problem, which is that everything is scaled by a factor of 2. For example, if I make a 10x10 window using window.create(sf::VideoMode(10, 10), "Window");, the window created will be 20x20 pixels, but SFML will treat it as a 10x10 window of 2x2 pixel units. This means that when I draw lines/shapes/text/images in the window, all their sizes are doubled. Hence, I can only fit a window with half the resolution on my Mac display.
If it helps, I am using a MacBook Pro M1 2020 with a 2560x1600 pixel Built-in Retina Display  running MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1. If I connect my computer to a 3840x2160 pixel monitor, the issue persists. I have not always had this issue, so I am unsure what caused it.
What is causing this scaling, and how can I prevent it?

You need to understand the difference between point size and pixel size. I am sure SFML has functions to get the current pixel size, as well as the point scale factor to help you out here.  Note also, that you won't always get the window size you asked for, so you would always want to ask the framework the internal pixel size after creation.  And of course, there is the camera concept which will also factor into where your drawn pixels appear.

@trojanfoe, thanks for the help. I've looked through the SFML documentation, but I didn't find any functions to get the current pixel size/point scale factor. The documentation says the width and height parsed to sf::VideoMode should be the width and height in pixels, so I'm not sure where it's going wrong. It shouldn't have anything to do with the camera because the issue persists regardless of whether I use sf:::View or not.
